# How can I use read.big.matrix to read multiple files in r?

Tags: r

I have a huge dataset consisting of hundreds of files and I need to use bigmemory (or similar) package to read the data. How do I use read.big.matrix with multiple files?

Comment: `library(data.table)
mydata<-fread("mylargefile.txt")`

Answer (score -1):

Could probably load the files iteratively from working directory and then merge the matrices.

```
setwd(path_to_files)
files <- list.files(path = ".")
number_of_matrices <- length(files)

#For faster computation set number of matrices
my_matrices <- vector("list", length = S)

for (file in 0:length(files)){
  my_matrices[file] <- read.big.matrix(filename=files[file])
}

#Assuming same columns this will merge them to one single:
massive_matrix <- do.call("rbind", my_matrices)
```

Have not tested the code, but this might give you an idea of how the problem could be approached?

Comment: The code gives the following error message:                                                               
> for (file in 0:length(files)){
+   my_matrices[file] <- read.big.matrix(filename=files[file])
+ }
Error in if (!file.exists(filename)) stop(paste("The file", filename,  : 
  argument is of length zero
>